# I need to know how to boot ubuntu on an existing Windows XP partition

Tags: partitioning, windows, windows-xp

I have an old PC running on Windows XP.  When I got it, I partitioned the hard drive.  I need to know how to install Ubuntu on *That* particular partition, since I have almost no space on my other drive.

Comment: How much RAM do you have and what are the general specifications of your computer. It may be better to go for one of the less hungry OS's like Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Ubuntu 18.04 and above**

New installations of recent versions of Ubuntu does not use a separate swap partition any more. They use a swap file by default.

**Remove the empty partition and keep the space unused.**

Ubuntu installation will find and use it. Ubuntu needs at least two partitions in formats not understood by Windows. So you cannot create partitions for Ubuntu to use from within Windows.

Particularly, Ubuntu needs a root partition with the mount point `/` in the format ext4, and a swap partition with no mount point in its own Swap-Linux format.

hope this helps

Comment: Did you get it to work?