# I really messed up my installation / wrong size for encrypted root partition

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have already installed Ubuntu 12.04 but I made a huge mistake while installing. While installing, the setup asked me to allocate drive space. I have a ~650GB hard drive that shows up as :C and :D in windows. :C is where I had Windows 7 installed + all user files. Before installation of Ubuntu :D was completely empty with about 400GB of drive space.

Ubuntu automatically chose :D to allocate space on. I decided against using the Advanced Settings because I didn't want to screw things up (and look what happened). It asked me to use the slider to indicate how much space I want for the swap (i think) and just regular storage space. I hastily slid it to where I thought I was giving myself the most free space but I ended up only giving myself 23GB of disk space, and ~400 to the other option.

I also selected the option to encrypt the /home directory, thinking I was making the right decision. I've downloaded GParted but I can't expand the / (ext4) obviously because its mounted. I also did another stupid thing and unmounted the ~400 part (sda5) thinking that's how I could add it back to ext4. I read somewhere that you can't edit/change/re-size mounted partitions.

(I tried to post a picture but I don't have enough rep)

it reads like this though:

```
/dev/sda5 (no key) ntfs (mo mountpoint/i unmounted it) 377GiB<br>
/dev/sda7 (key symbol) ext4 (mountpoint /) 22GiB
```

before I messed it up, sda5 read as:
/dev/sda5 (key symbol) ntfs (mount point /media/blahnumbersletters/) 377GiB

I've been searching around and many have suggested I boot the Ubuntu live CD and download LVM and crypt-setup, etc to expand the encrypted partition, but I can't seem to boot with the live CD. I've tried everything, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, most of which just take me to the GRUB boot-load program or they take me to the boot options but none of them give me the option to boot from the CD.

I don't know if this is necessary but my system is a Samsung Laptop NP-QX411.

I'm completely lost. What do I do here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**When you installed Ubuntu for the first time, you must have booted from some Live media (CD/DVD/USB) think** hard **and do the same thing again.**

**First,** You cannot work on partitions from which you booted! Use a Live DVD/USB to boot and use gparted from there. You **may be** able to increase the size of your root partition but, given that it is encrypted, I doubt it.

**Second,** given the situation you created, it may be best to start over.

Ubuntu needs to create its own type of partitions, `ext4`, as it cannot use Windows NTFS partition. So your partition called **D:** cannot be used to install Ubuntu. Delete that partition and create some empty space. Since you are starting over, delete the other partitions created by Ubuntu installation. Now you have a big empty space.

Now install Ubuntu again. It will find the big empty space and use it to create the partitions in the correct formats, ext4 and Linux-Swap.

See a similar question [I need to know how to boot ubuntu on an existing Windows XP partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306514/i-need-to-know-how-to-boot-ubuntu-on-an-existing-windows-xp-partition) and my answer.

Best of luck.